# Blender sort elements not working

Tags: sorting, build, blender, mesh

I'm trying to perform a sort elements on a mesh so that the build modifier will build the mesh in the order I want. The problem is that no matter which method of sort elements I try, the vertex indices stay the same. This is true for faces/edges/vertices. I brought up the vertex index debug tool and the order never changes no matter what I try. The version of blender I'm using is 2.77. Can anyone help me figure out what is going wrong please?

Comment: Are selecting all vertices before sorting? Are you updating the display? the index display doesn't update after it finishes, you need to move the 3dview a little so that is redraws.

Answer (score 2):

Сhoose **Face** selection mode, select all faces and then use sorting. I faced with the same problem, but my tutorial help me to understand the problem.
http://blender3d.com.ua/modifikator-build/